# Is Thor bulletproof?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Avengers: Infinity War* when the Guardians find Thor, he is alive even when his spaceship was destroyed by the Power Stone. Later Gamora says:

> It's like his muscles are made of Cotati metal fibers...

Given his anatomical strength, is he bulletproof, at least to human-scale weapons like guns and rifles?

Comment: He is highly impervious to blunt trauma, as taking hits from the Hulk and surviving attest, and since Loki was shown to be bulletproof it stands to reason that Asgardians are as well.
As for Stormbreaker, it doesn't have a "spell" on it like Mjolnir does, therefore logically anyone with the requisite strength can wield it, though probably not use it's other powers.